# Vue's dialog is repeatedly opened to create a mask

Tags: vuejs2

After I import the data in the backend, I click the el-button in this table to generate a pop-up QR code in the form of a dialog, and when there are multiple pieces of data, all pop-up windows will be opened at the same time, resulting in a mask

```
<template>
 <div style="background-color:rgb(245, 245, 245);height:150%;">
  <div id="main-div">
    <el-row style="width:980px;margin:0 auto;">
      <div id="survey-list" style="margin:0 auto; height:264px;">
        <el-table 
                        :data="surveyData.slice((currentPage-1)*pageSize,currentPage*pageSize)"
                        border style="width:100%;" 
                        :header-cell-style="{background:'#409EFF',color:'#fff'}"
                        :default-sort = "{prop: 'createTime', order: 'descending'}">
  <el-table-column width="60px"  label="分享" align="center" style="z-index: -5;">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                <el-button v-if="scope.row.publish===0" type="text" style="color:#409EFF;font-size:16px;" icon="el-icon-share" disabled></el-button>
                                <el-button v-if="scope.row.publish===1" type="text" style="color:#666;font-size:16px;" icon="el-icon-share"
                                    v-clipboard:copy="'http://localhost:8080/#/survey?sid='+scope.row.sid"
                                    v-clipboard:success="onCopy" 
                                    ref="qrCodeUrl"
                                    >
                               
                                </el-button>
                                
                                <el-dialog  title="问卷二维码"    :visible.sync="qrCodeVisible"  width="27%">
                                    <div id="qrCodeUrl"></div>
                                </el-dialog>
                                
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
</el-table>
</div>

</el-row>


</div>

</div>

</template>

<script>
import QRCode1 from 'qrcodejs2'
export default {
 return{
   qrCodeVisible:false
}
methods:{
   onCopy(e){
            // console.log(e);
            this.$message({
                type:"success",
                message: "问卷链接已复制到剪贴板，可用分享给小伙伴啦~~"
            });

           
              // 二维码弹框显示
              this.qrCodeVisible  = true;
                console.log("copy:"+e)
                // 生成二维码
                this.$nextTick(function () {
                    document.getElementById("qrCodeUrl").innerHTML = "";
                    let qrCodeUrl= new QRCode1("qrCodeUrl", {
                        
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        text: "http://localhost:8080/#/survey?sid="+e,
                        colorDark: "#409EFF",
                        colorLight: "#fff"
                    });
                });

     
            
        },
}
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to give the 'qrCodeVisible' property a variable to control whether each piece of data is displayed?

Comment: Add *condition* to control the dialog.